# Coloring the flash background in update 5.0.0 don't work

Tags: video.js

What i'm trying to do is to color the flash background.  by using this cdn

version : http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.9.1/video.js

i could color the the flash background like this:

```
            <script>

                var params = {};
                params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";

                videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";

                videojs.options.flash.params = params;


                </script>
```

But now i can't, because i'm using the new update:

http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.0-rc.2/video.js

how can i color the flash background in the new version of video.js?

can you also please show me...

FIX:

```
<script>


var params = {};

params.bgcolor = "#ffffff";



    videojs.setGlobalOptions({

                             flash: {

                             params:params,
                             swf: 'video-js.swf'

                           }
                           });
</script>
```

Comment: I FOUND A WORKAROUND AND A FIX BY MYSELF

Comment: I recommend you add it as an answer to your own question. This way when someone stumbles on this question in the future there is an answer.

Comment: I agree, that is right :)